# Pion decay: V-A vs. V coupling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, standard-model, chirality, pions, weak-interaction

For the Decay $$ \pi^- \to \mu^- \bar{\nu}_\mu $$ the Feynman rules for this tell us that the vertex couples with $\gamma^\mu (1-\gamma^5) / \sqrt{2} $. This gives me the reduced amplitude of
$$ M = \frac{G}{\sqrt{2}} q_\mu f_\pi \bar{u}(p)\gamma^\mu (1-\gamma^5)v(k) $$ where p is the four-momentum of the $\mu^-$ and $k$ for the $\bar{\nu}_\mu$.

The amplitude is (Pion has spin zero) $$\sum_{spin} |M|^2=|M|^2 = 4G^2 f^2_\pi m_\mu^2(p \cdot k)$$

But if we compare this with the vectorial coupling, that means replacing $\gamma^\mu (1-\gamma^5) / \sqrt{2} \to \gamma^\mu $ we get

$$ M = \frac{G}{\sqrt{2}} q_\mu f_\pi \bar{u}(p)\gamma^\mu v(k) $$ wich gives the probability amplitude 
$$\sum_{spin} |M|^2=|M|^2 = 2G^2 f^2_\pi m_\mu^2(k \cdot p)$$

Now my question is: why is the probability for coupling to all vectors half the probability of coupling to left (right) handed vectors for particles (anti particles)? I think the opposite makes more sense, that is, coupling two times more than just for left/right particles/antiparticles.

What's going on? Is there something wrong with my results?

Answer (score 1):

The pion is a pseudoscalar particle, which implies that $$\langle 0 |\bar{u} \gamma^\mu d | \pi \rangle =0$$ from parity conservation. So, the amplitude should be zero if the coupling is purely vector.